# Question about regular expression that expect one more match

Tags: python, regex

The sample string to match is :

```
'Python is simple1 and Java is strong2 that means 1simple nice 2strong nice too'
```

My regular rule is:

```
'(.+)(\d).*(\2)(\1)'
```

The result I expected as follows:

```
('simple', '1', '1', 'simple') 
('strong', '2', '2', 'strong')
```

But the present result is just the first one：

```
('simple', '1', '1', 'simple')
```

How to optimize the rule?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/KNaU4I/1

Comment: It work! Thanks a lot.